# Leaderboards and Google Play Services - SIGN_IN_REQUIRED

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, leaderboard

I'm trying to use GPS for leaderboards for a few days without success. Developing using Eclipse and cocos2d-x.

After doing miles of preparations, importing 3rd party libraries and copy/pasting code from a sample project, I'm still left with errors and questions. I'm an iOS dev forced to do Android/GPS dev for a while so bear with me. (I'm an iOS user as well, I do not use Android. I might not have enough knowledge of Google world terminology.)

- To use GPS for leaderboards, do I have to implement Google+ functionality into the app?
- The specific error I get to `onConnectionFailed()` when trying to connect the `GoogleApiClient` instance is: "SIGN_IN_REQUIRED". What does "sign in" mean - sign in to where? Sign in to Google Play Services? Sign in to Google+? Is either fine? Why does a "connect" call to GoogleApiClient not automatically launch some sign in procedure should it be necessary? How do I force the app to show some sign in UI to the user, or at least force the app to try to use the current Google account of the device?

Some instructions I've used are:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup
https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples (Using BaseGameUtils as dependency library)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards is more than sufficient to get it up and going. Just make sure you go through each instruction in that and linked pages correctly. As for the sign in as long as you've signed in to your Android device it will not prompt for any logins. The Google Play Services library will detect that and login automatically. In case you have logged in with multiple accounts it will prompt to pick one.

Comment: Except it does not detect any account being logged in. In any case, connection never succeeds and always fails with SIGN_IN_REQUIRED. I'm trying to bring up the leaderboards in game, but `mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()` returns false so can't proceed there.

Comment: Check [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client). It shows how to deal with the error you're getting.

Comment: Not really getting anywhere. Calling `result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);`  did nothing unless I copied a file from the sample project: res/layout/activity_main.xml and ran `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` inside `onCreate()` - it finally brought up an account selection UI - however selecting an account there just leaves the app in a state from which it does not proceed. The `onActivityResult()` is the last point which is called at this state, it ends with a resultCode of 1001, which is not the expected `RESULT_OK` needed for a successful `connect()` call.

Comment: Well at this point it's hard to suggest anything without checking your whole project.

Comment: I use pretty much a staple cocos2d-x (3.7) setup. Of course, the Java parts are only used to get the stuff running on Android AND to implement some native specific stuff like native alerts, IAP and of course leaderboards. I see a lot of references of Activities that inherit from "fragment" something. I have a hard time grasping what "fragment" something is, but the sole activity used for displaying cocos2d-x stuff on Android does NOT inherit from FragmentActivity. If that is related or not I cannot tell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87560/discussion-between-janithar-and-jonny).

Comment: I got it working. I honestly have no idea what I did, but I suspect one thing: for the whole sign-in thing we need to use properly signed APKs, signed with the release key. I knew that. But it seemed that once you had a debug APK on your device, and try to load a signed APK on top of it, the signin somehow does not seem to work. I had to manually uninstall the APK from device before loading a release APK onto it, or the sign in would not work - it (properly, after awhile) complained about not having a correct bundle id etc. This led me to fully uninstall before trying release builds.

Comment: Anyway, your first comment **is** and should be the correct advice here. Also in the end, I did not use the error handling stated at https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client, but rather the one in the sample project (BaseGameUtils of https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples ) That likely also fixed things.

Answer (score 0):

Following the (lengthy) instructions at https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards *should* be enough.